# Order of <source> tags in <audio> breaks browser compatibility

Tags: html, audio

I have the following audio tag on my page and have created the proper MP3 and Ogg Vorbis audio files using FFmpeg to allow me to hit as many modern browsers as necessary.  However, if I do not place the MP3 file first on the list the audio will not work in Safari. The same goes for the Ogg file with Chrome and Firefox. Should I be ordering or identifying them differently?

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="/plus/content/2012/08/025_conventions/abbotts.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="/plus/content/2012/08/025_conventions/abbotts.ogg"  type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Thus far, I've tried with the audio tag as controls or controls="controls" with no change. I also tried it with and without the 'type' attributes for each audio tag.

What have I missed?

Best,

Steven

Comment: I added a wav variant and was able to get things working in Safari and Firefox by listing them in order of WAV, OGG, MP3.  No luck Chrome, though. I can make Chrome work by putting OGG at the top of the list, but them Safari won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the page had been cached in Chrome so I was quite misled. All is well. Please ignore.

Comment: For posterity: use http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ for testing short HTML, to avoid caching